# Azure Data factory event trigger on new container with files added

Tags: azure-data-factory

Can azure data factory trigger event when new container added with files in storage account ? if not how this can be implemented

Comment: Did you get an answer? If not, please let us know what more are you looking for. If yes, 
https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers.

Answer (score 1):

You need to read [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/how-to-create-event-trigger) for full details.

[image]

The `Blob path begins with` and `Blob path ends with` properties allow you to specify the containers, folders, and blob names for which you want to receive events.

Comment: Thanks Shridhar. I am looking case if already Azure data factory is setup with container name value as "All container" for copying files from storage account to Data lake but if i add new container dynamically with files. Will azure data factory trigger copy files from new container(dynamically added) to data lake ?

Comment: @RohanG Did you try & face any issue with the above posted way?